# Webpack Error: Can't resolve style-loader from my webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, webpack

I created a django project with django apps, one of which contains React. I am basically capturing the data in a Django Rest API then sending data to my REact and thus rendering "dynamic" views.

But, when I try to style my react or do pretty much anything except use Javascript, I run into an error. The error I have right now is after installing the css loader for webpack via the documentation page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader, the error says: `ERROR in ./src/index.js 3:0-21 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\django-react\django_react\frontend'`

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
      ]
    }
  };
```

Please let me know what other files you would like. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you don't have the style-loader module installed: npm install -D style-loader. The WebPack documentation is a little weak; it tells you to install the css-loader but it forgets completely to tell you to install the style-loader.